# Why is $PATH different when executing commands via SSH and libssh?

Tags: ssh, rust

I'm trying to run a command on a remote host via libssh2 as wrapped by the [`ssh2` Rust crate](https://docs.rs/ssh2/0.3.1/ssh2/).

So I would like to run the command `cargo build`, but when I try to run it via libssh, I get the error:

```
cargo: command not found
```

However, when I ssh into the server manually from the command line everything works fine.

I have noticed that the `$PATH` is different when running ssh from the command line and libssh as well:

for instance when I `echo $PATH`

ssh gives me:

```
/home/<user>/.cargo/bin:/usr/share/swift/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bi
```

while libssh gives me:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So it looks like what's happening is that the modifications made to `$PATH` inside `.bashrc` and `.profile` are not making it in when running via libssh.

I also get the same behavior if I run `/bin/bash -c "echo ${PATH}"`

Why would this be the case, and is there any way to get the same behavior in both these cases?

Comment: Did you setup `/home/<user>/.cargo/bin:/usr/share/swift/usr/bin:` in .profile, try setting them in .bashrc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your libssh code for opening the ssh session and running the remote command. It would also be helpful to see a complete example of how you're running ssh interactively.

Comment: What is the exact issue can you please add the steps to reproduce.

Comment: How about `/bin/bash --login -c 'echo ${PATH}'` (note the single quotes)?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at that [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/why-does-remote-bash-source-bash-profile-instead-of-bashrc).

**TL;DR** A login shell first reads /etc/profile and then ~/.bash_profile. A non-login shell reads from /etc/bash.bashrc and then ~/.bashrc.